# How does Stata estimate regressions in with large data sets (given small matsize)?

Tags: regression, stata, large-data

The upper bound of Stata's $matsize$ is 11.000.

I need to 'manually' compute my variance-covariance matrix for a data set with 300k observations.

Thus, I'm wondering, how does Stata internally compute something like OLS:

$$(X'X)^{-1} X' y$$

when $X$ is that large? How can I manually do something similar?

Comment: Is your question specific to Stata? If so, it is off-topic here.  But it seems more like you are asking about how computers do this, not Stata specifically. If so, please edit the question by taking out references to Stata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does so in the compiled C code. You can see that if you type 'which regress', that will say that regress is a build in command. To handle large matrices you can use Stata's matrix language Mata.